# Not able to re-install php again on ubuntu

Tags: php

I want to update php version from 7.0 to 7.1 so i tried update php commands to update php version on ubuntu system.
But its not updated, so i removed php 7.0 version using purge command

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
```

These are the commands i tried for update php7.1 version after uninstall php7.0

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common
```

Getting error in command prompt as

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1'
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-common
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-common'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-common'
```

What im missing or did any thing wrong here?

Comment: Showing this error on command line when i tried to update php7.1 version Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1'
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-common
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-common'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-common'

Comment: Showing nothing for this command sudo apt-cache search php7 | more,  i mean not showing any packages on system when i ran this command.

Comment: Try `apt search php7 | more` instead.

Comment: PHP 7.1 is in maintenance mode, it only gets security fixes. You should upgrade to a newer version anyway.

Comment: It means i have try for PHP7.3 latest version ?

Comment: What makes you think that PHP 7.1 is part of Ubuntu 17.04? If you don't add a custom repository, there is only 7.0 available

Comment: i am not able to install 7.0 also again now and also how can i add custom repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `php7.1` and `php7.1-common` packages are not available in your apt's sources.
I am assuming you are using the latest Ubuntu 18 LTS.
You could install `php7.2` from the repositories, however older versions are not included anymore. You would have to install them manually.

**For Version 7.2**

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common
php -v
```

**For Version 7.1**

1. [Download](http://php.net/downloads.php) php
2. Extract the downloaded archive
3. Follow the included readme file

**other options**

If you are developing with different versions of PHP you might want to look into [PHP docker containers](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/)

[PHPDocker.io](https://phpdocker.io/) can be a good starting point.

EDIT: Also maybe consider posting this question on askubuntu instead, they might have more specific knowledge there.

Comment: No my ubuntu version is 17.04

Comment: getting same error for php7.2 Version also Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-common
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-common'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-common'

Comment: when i run php -v command its showing like this bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory

Comment: Can you list your sources please?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 system and i run this all commands from terminal.

Comment: Does `apt-cache search php` list any version of 7.1?

Comment: When i run this command sudo apt-cache search php its showing like this on command line
libnet-libidn-perl - Perl bindings for GNU Libidn
geany - fast and lightweight IDE
geany-common - fast and lightweight IDE -- common files
libgtksourceview-3.0-common - common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
netbeans - Extensible Java IDE

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the old version before adding the new one.

Try: `sudo apt-get remove php7.0*`

Also it is useful to list all php packages to check if you are installing all you need.

`sudo apt-get list php*`

Then it is safe to run your commands.

Comment: When i tried to run this command sudo apt-get remove php7.0* its showing error as

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0*'

and for this command showing this one on command line

E: Invalid operation lsit

Comment: sorry about the typo, the command was corrected to `list` maybe you version of PHP is different, try removing all of PHP, `sudo apt-get remove php*`

Comment: I removed php completely using sudo apt-get remove php* and it removed, Now how can i reinstall php latest version on my system ?